# show list of master tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to the SQL command to list all the master tables in the Postgresql database.

I have logged into a database called OpenBravo and when I run the command

```
\dt
```

It shows all the tables created in that database. I want to see the list of tables prefixed with pg_ which are master tables carrying the schematic details I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command:
\dt pg_*